# How to Draw path between 2 marker using GoogleMap flutter *Not Using MapView* Using GoogleMap flutter

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

I'm using [flutter_map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map#-readme-tab-) package and I need to draw path between 2 marker. I know [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) package provided draw path.

But I need to use [flutter_map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map#-readme-tab-) package. How can I draw route/path with `flutter_map` package ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [flutter_map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map#-readme-tab-) still does not provide creating routes

[someone ask from twitter to FlutterTeam](https://twitter.com/AmitJarsaniya07/status/1076166651815419905) and the answer is below:

[image]

Comment: but i have used https://medium.com/flutter-io/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245 this Map. If possible to draw the path in this Map